# Finding the finitely generated indecomposable modules over a given ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, group-isomorphism, principal-ideal-domains, finitely-generated

Let $R = k[x] / \langle x^p \rangle$, where $k$ is an (algebraically closed) field.

I want to find the finitely generated indecomposable modules over $R$ up to isomorphism, and I know that the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a PID (somehow) tells us that in this case they will be precisely the $R$-modules: $k[x] / \langle x^l \rangle$ for $l \leq p-1$.

My question is about how to actually use the structure theorem to do this, since $R$ is not a PID in this case.

I thought about trying to project from $k[x]$ into $R$ and then to use the correspondence theorem, but I couldn't figure out how to set it up.

Can anyone help? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

These are just the indecomposable modules over $k[x]$ which are
annihilated by $x^p$. The indecomposable modules over $k[x]$, which are finite-dimensional over $k$, are the
cyclic modules $k[x]/(f^m)$ with $f$ irreducible. In this case, the only
ones which count are $k[x]/(x^r)\cong R/(x^r)$ with $1\le r\le p$.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! I still don't quite understand how the structure theorem gives us this, because it seems like we are still considering $k[x] / \langle x^r \rangle$ as a $k[x]$-module, and not an $R$-module?

Comment: @Brock Yes, in general $R/I$-modules are just $R$-modules which are annihilated by $I$.

Comment: @Brock You're using the fact that the $k[x]/(x^n)$ modules are precisely the $k[x]$ modules annihilated by $(x^n)$.  So it suffices first to understadn them as $k[x]$ modules, and then throw out the irrelevant ones.

Comment: Yes that makes perfect sense! Thank you thank you!! :)

Comment: Actually I've changed my mind, I don't understand the logic of this argument: how do we know that the finitely generated indecomposable $R$ modules are precisely the finitely generated indecomposable $k[x]$ modules which are annihilated by $\langle x^p \rangle$? @LordSharktheUnknown